# `Product' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' CodingKey match property name in swift

Tags: swift, swift5, codable

I have one following `Codable` struct that compiler generate error `Product' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` after I remove the enum CodingKeys `amount, currencyCode`. anyone can show me why? it does not make sense when CodingKey and property name are the same and are needed to definte

```
public struct Product: Codable {
    let productID, productDescription: String
    let amount: Double
    let currencyCode, productItemID, state, lastUpdated: String
    let remaining: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productID = "productid"
        case productDescription = "description"
        case amount, currencyCode   // error compile after those coding key are removed
        case productItemID = "productItemid"
        case state, lastUpdated, remaining
    }
}
```

but following is totally fine

```
    public struct Product: Codable {
        let productID = ""
        let productDescription = ""
        let amount = 0.00
        let currencyCode = ""
        let productItemID = ""
        let state = ""
        let lastUpdated = ""

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case productID = "productid"
            case productDescription = "description"
            case productItemID = "productItemid"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

CodingKeys is an all or nothing affair. If you include one property you must include them all.

(It's a pity, and Apple knows it's a pain, but because of how the coding keys are autosynthesized behind the scenes, that's just how it works.)

Comment: i update my question but it seems like i do not need CodingKeys once I provide the default value why is that?

Comment: Because now this no longer needs initialization thru decoding; it is already initialized. But now you won't be picking up the decoded value! So by saying `let amount = 0.00` sure, now your code compiles without including `amount` in the coding keys, but if what you're decoding has an `amount` it will be ignored. So thanks to your "fix" your code _compiles_ but it doesn't actually _work_.